# How do I unmap a mapped network drive that also has an associated physical drive?

Tags: windows-7, remapping

I have 2 physical drives drives in my computer, C and D. Recently D "disappeared" and I assumed that it had stopped working but never removed it. I then mapped the letter D: to network share. Later the physical drive "reappeared" and when I navigate to D this is the drive I see. However the operating system also thinks that it's mapped to a network share and shows a red X next to the drive letter indicating that it can't reach that share but I can still navigate to the physical drive there.

How do I unmap this drive letter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not say which OS you are using. I am assuming win7:

- Right click on [my computer], select "manage".
- Go to disk Management.
- Right click on the partition with attached drive letter "D"
- Use "change drive letter and paths"
- Remove drive letter D:

After a reboot you should just get D: as a network mapping, one which you can delete (also use right click and then disconnect).  Restore the mapping to D: if whished.

Comment: what OS matters here. Windows at a cmd typing 'net use' will display current mappings and allow you to add or delete them